# DDD modifying more than one object per function (passing by reference)

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a method inside a root entity (of type `ProductOptionGroup`) that sets properties on a reference to another object (target, also of type `ProductOptionGroup`).

I have to pass in by reference as the target variable is modified in the below method snippet:

```
void SetOptionDependency(Product sourceProduct, Product targetProduct, ref ProductOptionGroup target)
{
    if (this.targetDependencyId == null)
    {
        this.targetDependencyId = target.Id;
    }

    if (this.targetDependencyId != target.Id)
    {
        // abort - reassignement of active dependency not allowed
    }

    if (this.map.Contains(sourceProduct.Id) == false)
    {
        // abort - the provided id is not associated with us
    }

    if (target.map.Contains(targetProduct.Id) == false)
    {
        // abort - the supplied id is not associated with the dependency target
    }

    // ** here the parameter passed in is modified **
    target.associationCount[targetProduct.Id]++;

    this.map.Add(sourceProduct.Id, targetProduct.Id);
}
```

I have put the code within the `ProductOptionGroup` aggregate as the business rules are most easily read there.

I guess the alternative could be to use a domain service to make the associations, but then some of the business logic and checking would come out of the entity and in to the service. I am not sure I like this idea.

The downside i see is that who ever is calling the method on the entity for would need to ensure that the entity is saved, along with the object modified by reference is also saved - the `ref` keyword on the method gives a big hint but is not explicit.

**My question is does modifying variables passed in by reference to a entity method violate any DDD rules?**

To give better context if needed, full code snippets below:

```
public class ProductOptionGroup
{
    string Id; // our Id
    string targetDependencyId; // we can link to one other ProductOptionsGroup by reference

    MapList<string, string> map = new MapList<string, string>();

    Dictionary<string, int> associationCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    void AssociateProduct(Product product)
    {
        this.map.AddKey(product.Id);
    }

    void DisassociatedProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (this.map.Contains(product.Id) == false)
        {
            // abort - the provided id is not associated with us
        }

        // check children are not referring to this product
        int count = 0;

        if (this.associationCount.TryGetValue(product.Id, out count) && count > 0)
        {
            // abort - this product is being referenced
        }
        else
        {
            this.map.Remove(product.Id);
        }
    }

    void SetOptionDependency(Product sourceProduct, Product targetProduct, ref ProductOptionGroup target)
    {
        if (this.targetDependencyId == null)
        {
            this.targetDependencyId = target.Id;
        }

        if (this.targetDependencyId != target.Id)
        {
            // abort - reassignement of active dependency not allowed
        }

        if (this.map.Contains(sourceProduct.Id) == false)
        {
            // abort - the provided id is not associated with us
        }

        if (target.map.Contains(targetProduct.Id) == false)
        {
            // abort - the supplied id is not associated with the dependency target
        }

        target.associationCount[targetProduct.Id]++;

        this.map.Add(sourceProduct.Id, targetProduct.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: First I don't know about any DDD **rules**, I know about PRINCIPLES. Next, DDD is more about a mindset and deals mostly with architecture issues not with the programming language features. DDD is high level design, what you ask is about a very specific technical implementation detail.

Comment: Hi @MikeSW, thanks for your comment - actually imho this is very much to do with DDD principles, specifically asking is it OK to modify an object via a parameter, or if this behavior would instead be better placed in a domain service (part of DDD architecture). Of course the trade off is keeping as much business logic within the entities themselves and not letting the model become anemic with all rules living in services. I am just not experienced enough with DDD to know the best practices in this scenario and if modifying by parameter is likely to introduce other issues

Comment: How would you modify an object state without passing parameters? Even when you change a property you're passing a parameter to the property setter

Comment: Agree but if you notice I am passing the 3rd parameter by reference which is modified also as part of the same operation.

Comment: Are you sure associationCount is necessary? can you try to model your aggregates such that only a single aggregate is edited? I ask this because it seems that OptionDependcy is a one-way constraint.
Also, It sounds like "Option Dependency" is an important concept in your model, maybe if you add it to your ubiquitous language, and model it as a value object, it will give you some more control in terms of where changes are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short I have concluded modifying the state of one variable inside the function of another function is really bad news, I view this as a side effect.

As was mentioned in the comments, needing to modify multiple things at once pointed to deeper domain insight that was waiting to be explored to allow a more natural and clean model, and associated code.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect